# How can I make server not to send 304 Not Modified

Tags: .htaccess, html, page-refresh

I recently encountered a problem in my website - some users do not have new version of the webpage displayed when it's updated. Although refreshing several times helps the problem, I don't want to add information on my site how to clear cache. Therefore I ask - how to change my .htaccess to make single page (single html document, but only this one - it's simple enough to not overload traffic) send new version every time. I searched, but most of the problem solutions are "How to clear browser cache".

Comment: Why don't you disable caching for this page in the first place with Pragma:no-cache, Cache-Control:no-cache, set expire in the future etc ?

Comment: I searched in Google "Pragma:no-cache" and I found how to do that:
`<Files myfile.php>
Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</Files>`
Thanks, now I have to test if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using PHP, you can do it from PHP like this:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");    // set the expire date in the past
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  // HTTP/1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache");                          // HTTP/1.0
```

Be sure to not send anything before the header (no echo, print etc ...).

Comment: Actually, .htaccess solution is more convenient for me, but I'll give PHP method a try.